# How to use dependent template default parameter with member accesses

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I do not know how to solve a problem which can be illustrated with the following `struct`:

```
template <typename T, unsigned WIDTH=T::width>
struct Handler {
    static unsigned const width = WIDTH;
};
```

There is a `struct` (in this case called `Handler`) which takes as template parameter a type `T`. In the codebase, where this `struct` is used, special binary types are used which have a member `width` (the number of bits of the type). As this `Handler` is supposed to only work with that binary type the second parameter `WIDTH` has the default value of `T::width`. Note that there is much more code into it but the code above should only provide a short explanation.

Now I want to be able to allow `float`s in this `Handler` with `WIDTH` set to `32` as the default parameter so that I can use `Handler<float>`. Apart from the template parameters, the `Handler` should work with `float` out of the box. Of course, if I directly use `Handler<float>` or even `Handler<float, 32>` (undesired solution) I get `error: ‘width’ is not a member of ‘float’`. So I need the code to be able to use the constant value `32` if `T` is `float` and `T::width` otherwise.

I tried to use ternary operators in the default parameter for `WIDTH` with the use of `std::is_same` and a special function for calculating the width depending on the provided type. Both attempts also result in the error above.

I also looked into template specialization but then I would also need to specialize `WIDTH` which would be needed to be provided (i.e. `Handler<float, 32>`) afterwards, wouldn't it?

I would really appreciate some tips/solutions.

Comment: Not the answer, but `<float, 32>` works for me. Just `<float>` doesn't, as expected.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh yeah, does work for `<float, 32>`, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a trait helper class to solve this. By default it'll use `::width` but can be specialised for other types:

```
template<typename T>
struct width_trait
{
    static unsigned const width = T::width;
};

template<>
struct width_trait<float>
{
    static unsigned const width = 32;
};

template <typename T, unsigned WIDTH=width_trait<T>::width>
struct Handler {
    static unsigned const width = WIDTH;
};
```